# React hooks, API-JSON HOLDER

Tags: reactjs, api, jsonplaceholder

```
 const [mekala, setMekala]= useState({posts:[]})
    
 <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" onClick{()=>deletePosts(post.id)}>DELETE</button>
    
 const deletePosts= async (pid) => {
    const { data } = await axios.delete(`${API}/${pid}`);
    console.log(data);
 }
```

whenever I perform deleteposts function, it is getting deleted on the server.

but to represent on UI, I need to do a filter function on the arrays.

How to bring the copy of states(mekala) here to write filter function so that I can again call setMekala to assign the deleted value to the state. To represent on UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
const deletePosts= async (pid) => {
  const {data}=await axios.delete(`${API}/${pid}`)
  const filteredPost = data.post;
  const filteredPostsList = mekala.posts.filter((post) => post.id !== 
  filteredPost.id);
  setMekala({posts: filteredPostsList})
}
```

Comment: If you would wrap the `deletePosts` function into a `React.useCallback` this solution would result in an unnecessary dependency. A better approach would be to use the `React.useState` (setMekala) in the function kind of way instead.

Answer (score 0):

This approach would result in fewer lines of code

```
const deletePosts = async (pid) => {
  const { data } = await axios.delete(`${API}/${pid}`)
  setMekala(prevState => prevState.posts.filter(post => post.id !== data.post.id))
}
```

And if you used it with `React.useCallback` you would have one dependency less.

```
const deletePosts = React.useCallback(async (pid) => {
  const { data } = await axios.delete(`${API}/${pid}`)
  setMekala(prevState => prevState.posts.filter(post => post.id !== data.post.id))
}, []); // <--- no deps needed in this case
```

Read about "functional updates" with the React.useState hook here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates